# Joining tables in MySQL with multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

### Rides (from one point to another)

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id   | start | end   | pointA| pointB|
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1    | xxx   |    xx |    1  |    2  |
| 2    | xxx   |    xx |    2  |    1  |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

### Points

```
+------+-------------+
| id   | desc        |
+------+-------------+
| 1    | "Chicago"   |    
| 2    | "NYC"       |    
+------+-------------+
```

So for example:

When a person rides from point A to point B it gets registerd in the `rides` table. `pointA` and `pointB` are both FK's in the `rides` table from the table `points`

How is it possible to get an SQL output in `MySQL` like this for a ride where `id = 1` for example:

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id   | start | end   | pointA| pointB|
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1    | xxx   |    xx |Chicago|  NYC  |
```

Comment: Which queries have you tried? (please post even queries that do not work or do not work as desired)

Comment: And you should probably read about JOINS: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: @Galz I used joins but I did not manage to work with the same points.id twice

Comment: Oh - in that case, see the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the same table twice, by giving each one a different alias:

```
SELECT r.id, r.start, r.end, pA.desc as pointA, pB.desc as pointB
FROM rides r
JOIN points pA ON pA.id = r.pointA
JOIN points pB ON pB.id = r.pointB
WHERE r.id = 1;
```